# Java extensions loader cannot find extensions after Java auto updates when application is running

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Java uses "`java.ext.dirs`" property to get the directory from which extensions should be loaded. My application starts (through JNI), runs OK and then (after java's auto-update) I get:

> java.lang.InternalError: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext\dnsns.jar

The updated version is in **jre1.8.0_65**, so no wonder the extension cannot be found. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The Jar was there before Java auto-updated. The problem happens on (many) client machines, so I cannot just recreate this file on my machine and get away with this ;)

Comment: It's not my extension, it's there when you install JRE. The problem is, that after the java auto-updates application should load extensions from "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\lib\ext" instead of "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\lib\ext"

Comment: The users aren't tech-savvy. I need to handle the situation without asking thousands of users to disable the auto-update feature of Java

Comment: Yes it exists ;) The jre1.8.0_65 has it's own version of the file (not copied from 60)

Comment: shouldn't it be using that file ? why does it still point to 60 ?

Comment: Can't you simply include the jar in the classpath of your program? That would cause a lot less hassles on deployment.

Comment: I will try that as last resort, but it is a plugin of JRE and a new version of that comes with each version of JRE. I don't think I am supposed to include it with my app...